# How to use the autonumber database column in SQL select statement

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I can't select the auto number column from an MS Access database because I keep getting this error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

I simply don't know what type (int, string, double, long...) should I put in my SQL statement to match the auto number column?

PS: I'm a total beginner

This is my code:

```
    string d = (string)Session["gouser"];
    string b = (string)Session["profile"];
    string s = (string)Session["stanum"];  // this is the auto number and its taken as a string 
    int y = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(s, out y);

    double X = y;

    DataTable m;

    m = DAL.SelectFromTable(" Select * FROM [Status] WHERE [user]='" + b + "' AND [number]='" + X + "'");
```

Comment: what is the type of column for variable X in the database?

Comment: it's defined as auto number in access (is there is another type that i'm supposed to check?)

Comment: Just thinking it may be because of Int at the access side and double in your code. Pass int and check once

Comment: did you try leaving it as a string and taking the single quotes out?
m = DAL.SelectFromTable(" Select * FROM [Status] WHERE [user]='" + b + "' AND [number]=" + X);

Comment: oh, it worked i kept it as a string as you said thank you

Comment: can you post working code as an answer here

Comment: STOP creating SQL statements using inline variables to reduce SQL Injection vulnerabilities. START good coding practices by using parameters which has been included in the comments and answers to your previous questions.

Comment: You really should start taking comments and answers to your previous questions to heart. You have been told multiple times to stop the practice of creating SQL statements using inline variables as well as showing all of the relevant code as the implementations of your `DAL` are not known. I understand that _"total beginner"_ situation and as such this is the ideal time to start good coding practices and asking fully qualified questions.

Comment: Why not open the database in access directly?  If you inspect the table design you'll see that an AutoNumber is either a Long Integer [32-bits] (the default type) or a Replication ID which is a Microsoft GUID and acts like a string value.  You could also just do a query `Select * FROM [Status]` and inspect the datatype of the returned fields.